# How to Transfer source code from XCode to Server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, xcode, shell

I want to transfer all the .h/.m and .framework files to my server while building the IPA. I have gone through many sites, but i didn't found way to do this at building IPA. Can we perform this task with this module via Shell script  (https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj).

Thanks in advance, Can anyone guide me to transfer my source files to Server while building IPA.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a source code control system with versioning like Subversion or Git.  Xcode has support for both of those.  You'll need a server that runs the system you want, but a Mac will run both subversion and git, so you can store your code on a mac.  The important thing is to store your code, and be able to see what changes you've made. Here's a link on how to set up git on a mac.  If you have other requirements, just google "set up subversion on windows" or "set up git on unix", whatever you want: [How to set up git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/)